# How can I override all array properties in appsettings.json at once

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog, appsettings

I know that using `appsettings.Development.json` files we can overide default settings. Also I know that we can change single properties in json array using `array:i` incidator.

The question is, is it possible to override all json values at once. Like in example below for loggin rules?

`appsettings.Development.json`

```
...
  "NLog": {
...
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "allfile"
      }
    ]
...
```

Example solution `appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "NLog": {
    "rules:*": {
      "minLevel": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With NLog ver. 4.6.7 you don't have to override all array-properties. You can use NLog Config variables as minLevel in the rules-section. Ex:

```
{
  "NLog": {
    "variables": {
      "MinLevelInfo": "Info"
      "MinLevelError": "Error"
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "${MinLevelInfo}",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "${MinLevelError}",
        "writeTo": "allfile"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example override in appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "NLog": {
    "variables": {
      "MinLevelInfo": "Debug"
      "MinLevelError": "Debug"
    }
}
```

Now you just have to override NLog variables, and they will be automatically applied by NLog. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2709 and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3184